# sum dataset rows values VB

Tags: vb.net

Hey I have VB app that get data from DB and store in excel but some column values must be stored in one excel column . I faced an issue to sum dataset values , an exception raised of System.InvalidCastException'

```
For i = 0 To dataset2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    sheet.Cells.Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(8) + dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(10)
Next
```

any help would be appropriated

Comment: In that case, `sheet.Cells.Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = CInt(dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(8)) + CInt(dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(10))` make it work? (Or use `CDbl` if they are meant to be of type Double.)

Comment: same not working , maybe because of null values

Comment: What should happen with null values? Should they be regarded as zero, or should the sum be null?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing what data is in the table. Pause the code in the debugger, point to the datatable, click the magnifying glass to open the datatable visualizer and send a screenshot of it (scrolled so we can see columns 9th and 11th)

Comment: @andrew Morton, null must be convert it to zero. Any help?